# search for the content of textarea1 in textarea2

Tags: php

how i can search for the content of textarea1 in textarea2 and print the whole line matches

example:

textarea1 contents(words)

```
content1
content2
content3
```

textarea2 contents(the lines)

```
this is content1
this is cont
this content3
```

so i want the printed matches lines like this

```
this is content1
this content 3
```

because content1 and content 3 in my textarea1

Comment: Well, what part are you stuck on? What have you tried? Can you show us the code of your current attempt or a fiddle?

Comment: Does it have to be PHP? You could accomplish the same thing client side with Javascript (or any other language obviously, but was thinking about it offloading to the client).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that is a PHP problem, not a JS one .

Comment: @Oddant I don't know where I implied that it is a JavaScript problem, the tag says PHP and I asked what OP was stuck on because I couldn't understand the context of this question otherwise and also wondered if he could show us some effort so we could tailor our answer to his level.

Comment: I think it's fair to ask if the OP meant JS because it is highly likely.

Answer (score 2):

Here comes an example using `preg_match()`, note that the search strings have to be quoted by `preg_quote()`:

```
$text1 = $_POST['text_area1'];
$text2 = $_POST['text_area2'];

// split search texts. in this case we use new line
$search = explode("\n", preg_quote($text1));

// now prepare for a regex
$regex = '~(' . implode('|', $search) . ')~';

// now split the text by newline
$lines = explode("\n", $text2);

foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(preg_match($regex, $line)) {
        print $line . "\n";
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
this is content1
this content3
```

---

Note that you may refine the way how you separate the search strings. In my example I split them by newline, but you may wish them additionally splitted by spaces or `,` ...

Comment: You might better answer the question if you set the two variables by reading in a couple named parameters.

Comment: i replaced it with but i got error

$needle = $_GET['text1.txt']
$haystack = $_GET['text2.txt']

Answer (score 0):

```
$textarea1 = "content1\ncontent2\ncontent3";
$chunks = explode("\n", $textarea1);

$textarea2 = "this is content1\nthis is cont\nthis is content3";
$lines = explode("\n", $textarea2);


foreach ($chunks as $c)
    foreach ($lines as $l)
        if (strpos($l, $c))
            echo $l . '<br>';
```

Answer (score -2):

To use regex in this case is a bit too much in my opinion, just use basic string-functions offered by php:

```
// the \n is the line break smybol used in the textarea
$needle = "content1\ncontent2\ncontent3"; // this text is probably received via $_GET['text1'] or something similar
$haystack = "this is content1\nthis is cont\nthis is content3";

// get all lines
$needle_lines = explode("\n", $needle);
$haystack_lines = explode("\n", $haystack);

foreach($haystack_lines as $hline) {
  foreach ($needle_lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($hline, $line) === false)
      continue;
    echo $hline."<br />";
    //continue the outer foreach since we already found a match for the haystack_line
    continue 2;
  }
}
```

Update #1:
This code iterates through all lines in your haystack and checks for every needle in it.
If it finds one needle the line is printed via echo and we proceed with the next line of the haystack - is there anything more needed?

Comment: no need to compare the count of the two haystack, that is totally not reliable since the number of lines between the two can highly be different..

Comment: plus he said "because content1 and content 3 in my textarea1", that (i think) means one line must be matched by the presence of any words in the first haystack.

Comment: i have list1.txt contine 100 names

i want to get the emails of them 

from list2.txt contain 1000 names with emails like that (name : email)
its very tired to search for names one by one
so i want to print the lines that continue the name and email of my 100 names that i serch for
in one click
i thinked to make simple php code contine 2 textarea
textarea1
textarea 2
and put (names) in  textarea1
and (name : email) in textarea2
and make compare or search for my names's emails and print it